# Missing dependencies when building to jar with javaFx and intellij IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

I am trying to build my project to a runnable jar in intellij IDEA; I am using javaFx for the GUI. I have successfully run/built the project multiple times through development but now I have created an artifact as followed in another [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32749608/intellij-idea-javafx-packager-access-denied) and this didn't include the javafx dependency even though I selected it to and it's in the build path, My message is:`Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application` even though I have added the dependencies in build and to the environment variables. Is there a solution?

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify what JDK and JavaFX versions do you use?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message when trying to run a JAR file created with JavaFX 11 in IntelliJ.

You're just missing two additional steps:

- create an additional main method in a class which doesn't extend application and simply calls your real main method.
- include the **.so** files in the JAR.

To do that in IntelliJ, it's:

File > Project Structure > Artifacts > click the "+" symbol > File > and then select all the .so files in the JavaFX folder.

Answer (score 0):

scenario:

1. you carefully follow "https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-javafx",
   the "Non-modular with Maven"
2. you app does run inside IntelliJ
3. Yo cannot build a correct jar
4. You DON'T want to fight with

*..EXPORT / .. --wtf .... :
--module-path $PATH_TO_FX --add-modules*

5. due to a known problem, (http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/openjfx-dev/2018-June/021977.html)

We have to use an helper class.

6. add the following class "Helper" and make it the "MAIN" class

   public class Launcher {

   ```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        App.main(args);
    }
   ```

   }
7. change refs in maven from you actual name (if starting from javafx site sample.. ) to this Launcher class:

from:

org.example.App

to:

org.example.Launcher

8. add SHADE plug in to manven:

   org.apache.maven.plugins
            maven-shade-plugin
            3.2.0

   ```
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>shade</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                    <shadedClassifierName>project-classifier</shadedClassifierName>
                    <outputFile>shade\${project.artifactId}.jar</outputFile>
                    <transformers>
                        <transformer implementation=
                                             "org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">

                            <!-- original:
                            <mainClass>org.example.App</mainClass>
                             -->

                            <mainClass>org.example.Launcher</mainClass>

                        </transformer>
                    </transformers>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
   ```
9. to run in intelliJ, change main class in "Edit Configuration" to "Launcher"
10. ... run "mvn clean!" :)

PS:
You can see ti in action here:

https://github.com/ingconti/SampleJavaFxWithResize